# Error running nextjs with PM2 on Azure App Service on Linux

Tags: node.js, azure, next.js, azure-web-app-service, pm2

The pipelines and releases seem to work finely as they get the artifact deployed on the app service or so it seems as the output error happens on start of the PM2 process.

I haven't found anything on this error on google, and don't know if there is a way to update PM2 on the app service machine as PM2 itself suggests.

These are the logs.

***Error message***

[image]

***summary image***

[image]

I was expecting the app to work and no longer show an application error as I fixed both build and release pipelines.

This is a picture of the important bit of info of the error as its really long

Answer (score 0):

Check the below steps to run `nextjs with PM2`.

- First create a `nextJS app`.

***Run `npm run dev` command to run the app in development.***

- Deploy the app to Azure Linux App Service.

Open the `SSH` of the Azure App Service to run the PM2 commands.

- We can open directly with the below URL.
  ***Path to SSH*** - `https://YourDeployedAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/`

[image]

***OR***

- Navigate to the deployed `Azure Linux App` => `Advanced Tools` => `Go` => `SSH`.

[image]

Run the below command to install `PM2`.

```cs
npm install pm2 -g
```

[image]

[image]

Thanks @[Azure OSS Developer Support](https://azureossd.github.io/2022/02/22/Using-PM2-on-App-Service-Linux/) for the commands.

- In `Configuration` section => `General Settings` add the Startup command.

```cs
 pm2 start site/root/index.js --name mynpmnextapp
```

Your path may differ for the index.js file.

My app entry point is `index.js`.For some apps it can be `server.js`.Change it according to your app.

[image]

> cannot find module `../build/output/log'

Make sure you are not running the `PM2` with the output folder. As mentioned above it has to be the entry point either `server.js` or `index.js` based on your code files.

> don't know if there is a way to update PM2 on the app service

In the `KUDU Console` use `npm install pm2@latest -g` to update the PM2.

References taken from [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-nodejs?pivots=platform-linux#run-with-pm2) and [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2).